# Unable to ltrim when Redis list is having only one record

Tags: node.js, database, redis, in-memory-database

I try to trim the records in `redis` queue using the following command. But unfortunately, unable to trim if there is only one item in the list.

```
ltrim key, -1, 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ltrim key start_index stop_index` command, the index is zero based. `0` is the index of the first element, and `-1` is the index of the last element. If `start_index` is larger than `stop_index`, Redis clears the list, i.e. deletes the `key`.

Base on the above definition, let's take a look at your command:

```
ltrim key -1 0
```

The `start_index` is `-1`, i.e. the index of the last element, and the `stop_index` is 0, i.e. the index of the first element.

If the list has more than one elements, then the `start_index` is larger than the `stop_index`. In this case, the list / `key` will be deleted. However, if there's only 1 element in the list, both `start_index` and `stop_index` are the index of the first (also the last) element of list. You command has the same effect as: `ltrim key 0 0`. With this command, Redis keeps the first element (also the only element) of the list, and the list won't be *trimmed*.

By the way, do you want to delete the list? If you do, just call `del key`.